# "no such column" on WITH UPDATE statement

Tags: sqlite, syntax

I'm looking directly at the [sqlite documentation for the UPDATE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html), and I have some SQL which I believe meets the syntax specified:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x (y INTEGER); 
INSERT into x SELECT value FROM table WHERE id IN (6,7,12,15) ORDER by value ASC; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE z (y INTEGER);
INSERT INTO z (y) VALUES (6),(7),(12),(15);
WITH NewValues(f,g) AS
    (SELECT a.y AS f,b.y AS g FROM 
        (SELECT rowid,y FROM x) AS a,
        (SELECT rowid,y FROM z) as b
     ON a.rowid==(1+b.rowid%4)
    )
UPDATE table
SET value = NewValues.g
WHERE NewValues.f = table.id;
```

But when I try to execute this statement, I get the error:

```
near "WITH": syntax error
```

The code before the `WITH` is fine; if I just run the sub-select of the `WITH` and remove the remainder of the `UPDATE` it returns a table as I expect.  The syntax chart very clearly shows that I can put the `WITH` at the start of the statement.  So what am I doing wrong?

Update:
I have tried out one of the simple [examples](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) given:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
    cnt(x) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cnt WHERE x<1000000)
SELECT x FROM cnt;
```

And I get a syntax error from that too!  My first thought was maybe I don't have a new enough version of sqlite or something, but I don't see any mentions of a minimum version that it was introduced in.

Update 2:
I downloaded the latest sqlite which is 3.8.5, whereas I was running 3.7.12.  This fixed the `WITH` syntax error, so it appears that it does indeed require a rather new version of Sqlite.  However I am still getting:

```
no such column: q.g
```

Which I don't understand in the context of the query, since I have defined it two ways.

Comment: Are you sure you can have a FROM in your update? It didn't look like it to me

Comment: Try SET value = NewValues.v... remove the from

Comment: @MillieSmith Yeah, once I got past the `WITH` issue (apparently it *was* introduced after 3.7.12) I got a syntax error on `FROM` so I tried your suggestion, but now I get "no such column: NewValues.v".

Comment: @MillieSmith err oops, I think that should be NewValues.g, but I get the same error there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reference the WITH CTE you need to select from it.

Try this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x (y INTEGER); 
INSERT INTO X (y) VALUES (6),(7),(12),(15);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE z (y INTEGER);
INSERT INTO z (y) VALUES (6),(7),(12),(15);


WITH NewValues(f,g) AS
    (SELECT a.y AS f,b.y AS g FROM 
        (SELECT rowid,y FROM x) AS a,
        (SELECT rowid,y FROM z) as b
    ON a.rowid==(1+b.rowid%4)
    )
UPDATE task
SET value = (SELECT g FROM NewValues WHERE NewValues.f = task.id)
WHERE id IN (SELECT f FROM NewValues);
```

Comment: But I still need the `WHERE` clause, because "the UPDATE affects only those rows for which the result of evaluating the WHERE clause expression as a boolean expression is true."  In the statement you have provided it is affecting all rows, effectively nulling the `value` field on all rows on in the `WITH` select.

Comment: To clarify, I am not sure what the `WHERE` clause should be... I also cannot use `NewValues.f` as is, but am not sure how to reform that into a SELECT.

Comment: Looks like I need to append `WHERE table.id IN (SELECT f FROM q)`

Comment: @Michael, yes, I didn't have your test data for `Task` so I didn't know if you had data for the whole table or just part. I'll add the `WHERE` clause you said. Thanks for clarifying.